# How do I get a fisherman villager in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I get a fisherman villager in Minecraft? I need to know which profession and career number it is.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I summon villagers with certain professions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343459/how-can-i-summon-villagers-with-certain-professions)

Comment: @pppery This older question doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that newer one. This one's more specific. Relevant [meta] post: [Is a question a duplicate just because it asks for something that can be part of another question's answer?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7359/4797)

Answer (score 2):

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:2}
```

[list of profession and career IDs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Professions_and_careers):

[image]

Assign `CareerLevel` to unlock more trades at start.

Answer (score 2):

The Fisherman is a subset of the brown coat villager, The brown coat's profession id is 0, while the fisherman subset (Career) is 2, so to summon one, you need to do this:

```
/summon villager <x y z coordinates> {Profession:0,Career:2}
```

Hopefully I Helped.
Ref: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Professions_and_careers

Answer (score 1):

The Fisherman is a subset of the Brown Robed Villager and is listed as the second career number for the Brown Robed Villager.

via https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading