# How can I summon villagers with certain professions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a world to show off each and every type of villager in Minecraft 1.14 (snapshots). I'm wondering if there is a command to summon specific villagers with certain professions (I already know how to make specific trades though). Is it nbt data or what? I just need to summon them into my world with `/summon villager ~ ~ ~`. I need it for each biome, profession, career, and trade tier.

Comment: What sort of help do you actually need?

Comment: Just need command to summon specific villagers with certain professions, etc. (I already know how to make specific trades though). Just need to summon them into my world with /summon villager ~ ~ ~.......

Comment: Is it nbt data or what? I also need ids for each. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.14, this sort of data is all contained within the villager's `VillagerData` compound. It contains

- `profession`, which is a string. It can be any of `minecraft:armorer`, `minecraft:butcher`, etc.
- `type`, which is also a string. It can be any of `minecraft:desert`, `minecraft:jungle`, etc.
- `level`, which is an integer. This should be pretty self explanatory.

So an example command might be

```
summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData:{type:"minecraft:plains",profession:"minecraft:mason",level:2}}
```

You can find all the valid `profession` and `type` values [here on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Data_values).

Comment: @SeenNorvell If the answer was correct, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SeenNorvell That would just be `/data merge entity <target> {VillagerData:{...}}`, where `<target>` selects a single villager and `...` is the type, profession, etc. you want.