# Minecraft, how to summon specific villager in 18w50a?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried every command I could find on the internet and none of them works. -.- 
I want a toolsmith but:

```
/summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:3, Career:3}
```

spawns just a random villager....

Comment: Tip: Never use spaces in NBT. It can break stuff.

Comment: :O Didn't knew that, thanks for the info!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I summon villagers with certain professions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343459/how-can-i-summon-villagers-with-certain-professions)

Answer (score 3):

After digging in the wiki, and learning how commands works, the command format has changed in 1.14. Now you have to input:

```
/summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData: {level: 1, profession: "minecraft:toolsmith", type: "minecraft:plains"}}
```

Professions (their names) are listed here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager

Comment: if I do any one of these commands, they just spawn a regular villager that does make the sounds and everything, but I can't actually trade with them...

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn a villager in 1.14 the villager will not have a profession unless you have the corresponding decoration block. Example: a toolsmith needs a grindstone, a butcher needs a smoker, a cleric needs a brewing stand etc. etc.

The moment you place the proper decoration block the basic villager will pick up the profession. The moment you break the decoration block the corresponding villager will demote itself back to its basic form.